# How to sanitize url from XSS in Front End Application?(Angular/JADE)

Tags: javascript, xss, owasp

Can someone suggest some way to prevent Front End application(Jade/Pug & Javascript) from XSS attack using some Api(we dont want to use regex)?

I have gone through OWASP Antisamy link but that is using jars and it is completely java based. So, can you suggest some open source Api method to prevent Fully Front End Angular 1.5 application(Jade/Pug and Javascript) from XSS Attack.

Comment: Please see this article for some details on why this opinion-requesting question isn't appropriate:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: AntiSammy is no longer supported by OWASP. The new replacement is OWASP HTML Sanitizer. Anyway, Angular seems to be good to fight XSS on the client. But to fight XSS you need to add output encoding on the server